# XWiki error 500 on fresh install

Tags: java, servlets, xwiki

I recently did a fresh install of XWiki 10.6.1 on tomcat 8.5.32 but I can't even get to the main page. I've tried using both Java 8 and Java 10 but both give identical results. I followed the instructions here: [link](https://www.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Documentation/AdminGuide/Installation/InstallationWAR/). My permanent data directory is set to /srv/xwiki and the tomcat user owns that folder. I'm using apache derby as my database and have commented out/uncommented the sections in hibernate.cfg.xml accordingly. What am I doing wrong? My stack trace is linked below as it exceeds the maximum character allowance for stackoverflow:

[Stack Trace](https://hastebin.com/axerokeqot.coffeescript)

Comment: I don't know anything about XWiki, but the root cause in your stack trace (at the very bottom) is _org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find a getter for conentStore in class com.xpn.xwiki.doc.DeletedAttachment_. Note that the missing getter is for **conentStore** (not **contentStore**) which looks suspicious. I couldn't find any bug reported for this issue, but I see plenty of references to **contentStore** in the GitHub code,  and none for **conentStore**. Check Derby's Wiki tables to see whether there is a column named **conentStore** or **contentStore**.

Comment: @skomisa I'm currently unable to check if this is the issue or not however inside of one of their jars I found the derby mapping file which contains the following line:
`<property name="conentStore" type="string" column="XDD_CONTENTSTORE" length="50" />`. I think someone made a typo so I should probably file a bug report if this does indeed end up being the issue. If this does end up being an issue I'll let you know so you can post the answer if you want.

Comment: I agree that it looks like a typo. Perhaps try reinstalling after changing that property value from `name="conentStore"` to `name="contentStore"` in the mapping file to see if that fixes the problem? If it does you can still file a bug report, but also give them the fix.

Comment: @skomisa adding that t fixed all of my problems. Thanks for having better eyes than I did haha. I probably never would have caught something so subtle.

Comment: Cool. I encourage you to raise a bug report anyway, to help XWiki and other users who may end up facing the same issue. Also post your fix as an answer here to help other SO users. I'm a bit surprised that there is nothing about your problem on the web, but I suppose someone always has to be the first, and this time it was you...

Comment: @skomisa yeah I plan on filing a bug report. I was going to let you post the answer so you get the rep points since you were the one that found it but I can post it if you don't care.

Comment: I don't care  - go for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file `xwiki.derby.hbm.xml` inside of `WEB-INF/lib/xwiki-platform-legacy-oldcore-10.6.1.jar` has a typo in the property name for the `contentStore` mapping. Adding a t to the name to change it from `conentStore` to `contentStore` fixes the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your analysis, I created and fixed it in https://jira.xwiki.org/browse/XWIKI-15507. Derby use case is indeed not tested much...